# Unable to connect to MongoDB via node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a Node JS script to connect to MongoDB via mongoose library. When i tried to connect to MongoDB server i am getting `MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`. I tried in github, stackoerlow and websites suggested by google. But, nothing helpful. I created clusters in mongodb and everything works fine and i whitelisted the IP using `0.0.0.0\0`.

Thanks in advance..!!!

[image]

Comment: Does your mongo url works fine with mongo compass?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I usually use for mongo connection.

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Db } from 'mongodb';
import config from '../config';

export default async (): Promise<Db> => {
  const connection = await mongoose.connect(config.databaseURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
  return connection.connection.db;
};
```

where `config.databaseURL` is mongo url with username and password.

Please try using your mongo url in mongo compass. That url should work with this code.

Comment: sandip i wrote the code but unable to connect with `databaseurl`.

Comment: I think the problem is with databse url. i gave correct password and username.

Comment: Can you connect it using `Mongo Compass` or `Robo 3T`?